# Setting an attribute dynamically in mithril.js

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I'd like to set an attribute in mithril.js inside the `oninit` function. For example,

```js
m('img', {
    oninit: (vnode) => {
        vnode.attrs.src = 'A url string';
    }
})
```

I want to check for certain conditions before setting this attribute and I'd rather not use the ternary operator because that would get messy. The above example half worked, on logging `vnode`, the `attrs` object has the correct `src` string, however in the DOM, `src` is set to `null` for some reason.

I'm looking for a simple solution and not something like, give an `id` to the element and use it to change the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually such code could be placed in the component as a method or as a function when using a closure component.

This is in a component just for an image but such work could be done in a parent component that rendered that IMG directly.

```
function DynamicImg() {
  function imageAttrs(vnode) {
    let src = 'configurable';
    return {src: src};
  }
  return {
    view: function (vnode) {
        return m('img', imageAttrs(vnode));
    }
  }
}
```

Setting an attr in init would not last as the view function would be called without it immediately.  Since it is called at every render.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution, this worked for me.

```js
m('img', {
    src: (() => {
        return 'A url string';
    })()
})
```

You can define the function elsewhere and call it as well.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as [`m('img', { src: someVar })`](https://jsfiddle.net/3p2v6f8e/)? Immediately invoking it seems to remove the benefit of the callable, in other words.

Comment: @JaredFarrish In this case yes, but this is an example. What I wanted was to add a few if statements and return something based on that condition.